# How to save Object Graphs with one stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, orm, ado.net

Be advised: this is my "[share your knowledge](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)" question!

I have a web client which sends data to my ASP.NET application in JSON format. The data is an object graph or a collection of object graphs.

The data is deserialized to C# object graphs with Web Api controller. I want to save that C# object graph with ADO.NET and **one** stored procedure.

And I want to do this without **GUID** and **EF**! :)

Let's suppose that a web client sends the object graphs consisting of three objects:

- `GrandRecord`
- `Record`
- `ChildRecord`

Let it be a collection of `GrandRecords` where:

- each `GrandRecord` has a collection of `Records`
- and each `Record` has a collection of `ChildRecords`
- Id value is integer and autogenerated by database
- and while an object is not saved in database, Id has value = 0

Here is the sample of object graph collection (or object graphs) :

```
                      Id, Name
GrandRecord           1,  (A)
    Record            |-- 2, (A)A
        ChildRecord       |-- 3, (A)Aa
        ChildRecord       |-- 0, (A)Ab
    Record            |-- 0, (A)B
        ChildRecord       |-- 0, (A)Ba
        ChildRecord       |-- 0, (A)Bb
GrandRecord           0,  (B)
    Record            |-- 0, (B)A
```

Or the same in JSON format:

```
grandRecords: [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "(A)",
        records: [
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "(A)A",
                childRecords: [
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        name: "(A)Aa",
                    },
                    {
                        id: 0,
                        name: "(A)b",
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 0,
                name: "(A)B",
                childRecords: [
                    {
                        id: 0,
                        name: "(A)Ba",
                    },
                    {
                        id: 0,
                        name: "(A)Bb",
                    },
                ]
            }        
        ]        
    },
    {
        id: 0,
        name: "(B)",
        records: [
            {
                id: 0,
                name: "(B)A",
                childRecords: []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

On the web server in ASP.NET controller the above JSON string is deserialized into object graphs of three classes:

```
public class GrandRecord
{
    public  Int32          Id       { get; set; }
    public  String         Name     { get; set; }
    public  IList<Record>  Records  { get; set; }
}

public class Record
{
    public  Int32               Id             { get; set; }
    public  Int32               GrandRecordId  { get; set; }        
    public  String              Name           { get; set; }
    public  IList<ChildRecord>  ChildRecords   { get; set; }
}

public class ChildRecord
{
    public  Int32   Id        { get; set; }
    public  Int32   RecordId  { get; set; }
    public  String  Name      { get; set; }
}
```

Now the object graphs has to be saved with one stored procedure into three database tables:

```
create table dbo.GrandRecords
(
    Id    int          not null  identity  primary key clustered,
    Name  varchar(30)  not null
);

create table dbo.Records
(
    Id             int          not null  identity  primary key clustered,
    GrandRecordId  int          not null  foreign key (GrandRecordId) references dbo.GrandRecords (Id) on delete cascade,
    Name           varchar(30)  not null
);

create table dbo.ChildRecords
(
    Id        int          not null  identity  primary key clustered,
    RecordId  int          not null  foreign key (RecordId) references dbo.Records (Id) on delete cascade,
    Name      varchar(30)  not null
);
```

The question is **how**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the **table valued parameters** for stored procedure is a part of the answer!

Having these user-defined table types:

```
create type dbo.GrandRecordTableType as table
(
    Id    int          not null   primary key clustered,
    Name  varchar(30)  not null    
);

create type dbo.RecordTableType as table
(
    Id             int          not null   primary key clustered,
    GrandRecordId  int          not null   ,
    Name           varchar(30)  not null

);

create type dbo.ChildRecordTableType as table
(
    Id        int          not null   primary key clustered,
    RecordId  int          not null   ,
    Name      varchar(30)  not null    
);
```

The stored procedure for saving the above object graphs starts with:

```
create procedure dbo.SaveGrandRecords
    @GrandRecords  dbo.GrandRecordTableType  readonly,
    @Records       dbo.RecordTableType       readonly,
    @ChildRecords  dbo.ChildRecordTableType  readonly
as
```

So we have to collect all data by types (`GrandRecord`, `Record` and `ChildRecord`), create ADO.NET DataTables and pass them to the stored procedure.

But! Because our tables in Database are linked by foreign keys `GrandRecordId` and `RecordId`, we have somehow to persist that link while converting the object graph into the separate DataTables.

What is more, the identities of new objects have to be unique! Otherwise, we can not distinguish the Records of GrandRecord (A) from the Records of GrandRecord (B).

However, as we remember from the question, new objects have Id = 0!

To fix this, let's assign **ever increasing negative identities** to object Ids, if they are equal to 0:

```
var id = int.MinValue;

foreach (var grandRecord in grandRecords)
{
    if (grandRecord.Id == 0)
        grandRecord.Id = id++;

    foreach (var record in grandRecord.Records)
    {
        if (record.Id == 0)
            record.Id = id++;

        record.GrandRecordId = grandRecord.Id;

        foreach (var childRecord in record.ChildRecords)
        {
            if (childRecord.Id == 0)
                childRecord.Id = id++;

            childRecord.RecordId = record.Id;
        }
    }
}
```

Now it's time to populate the Data tables.

For example, here is how to prepare a DataTable with `Records` data:

```
var recordTable = new DataTable("RecordTableType");

recordTable.Columns.Add( "Id"            , typeof( Int32  ));
recordTable.Columns.Add( "GrandRecordId" , typeof( Int32  ));
recordTable.Columns.Add( "Name"          , typeof( String ));


var records = grandRecords.SelectMany(gr => gr.Records);

foreach(var record in records) 
{
    table.Rows.Add(new object[] {record.Id, record.GrandRecordId, record.Name});
}
```

So after the DataTables are prepared, the stored procedure will receive the following data in table valued parameters:

@GrandRecords

```
+-------------+------+
|     Id      | Name |
+-------------+------+
|           1 | (A)  |
| -2147483648 | (B)  |
+-------------+------+
```

@Records

```
+-------------+---------------+------+
|     Id      | GrandRecordId | Name |
+-------------+---------------+------+
|           2 |             1 | (A)A |
| -2147483647 |             1 | (A)B |
| -2147483646 |   -2147483648 | (B)A |
+-------------+---------------+------+
```

@ChildRecords

```
+-------------+-------------+-------+
|     Id      |  RecordId   | Name  |
+-------------+-------------+-------+
|           3 |           2 | (A)Aa |
| -2147483645 |           2 | (A)Ab |
| -2147483644 | -2147483647 | (A)Ba |
| -2147483643 | -2147483647 | (A)Bb |
+-------------+-------------+-------+
```

### Object graph saving technique

In order to update existing, insert new and delete old data, SQL Server uses the MERGE statement.

The MERGE statement has the OUTPUT clause. The OUTPUT in MERGE statement can collect just inserted Ids as well as the Ids from the source (parameter) table.

So the technique "to save all three tables with correct foreign keys" is to collect the `InsertedId` - `ParamId` pairs from the first table and to **translate** those values for the second. Then do the same for the second and third tables.

- If a record exists in a table the MERGE does UPDATE, `inserted.Id` and `source.Id` are equal to the existing Id.
- If a record does not exist in a table the MERGE does INSERT, `inserted.Id` is equal to the new Id and `source.Id` is equal to the negative identity.
- If a record does not exist in source (parameter) table the MERGE does DELETE,  `inserted.Id` and `source.Id` are equal to NULL, but `deleted.Id` has Id of deleted record.

Here is the stored procedure which saves our object graphs:

```
create procedure dbo.SaveGrandRecords
    @GrandRecords  dbo.GrandRecordTableType  readonly,
    @Records       dbo.RecordTableType       readonly,
    @ChildRecords  dbo.ChildRecordTableType  readonly
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    declare @GrandRecordIds table (  -- translation table
        InsertedId  int  primary key, 
        ParamId     int  unique
    );

    declare @RecordIds table (       -- translation table
        InsertedId  int     primary key, 
        ParamId     int     unique, 
        [Action]    nvarchar(10)
    );

    -- save GrandRecords 

    merge into dbo.GrandRecords as target
        using 
        (
            select Id, Name from @GrandRecords
        ) 
        as source on source.Id = target.Id

    when matched then
        update set                
            Name = source.Name        

    when not matched by target then                                                         
        insert ( Name )
        values ( source.Name )

    output            -- collecting translation Ids
        inserted.Id,
        source.Id
    into @GrandRecordIds ( 
        InsertedId , 
        ParamId    );


    -- save Records 

    merge into dbo.Records as target
    using 
    (
        select
            Id             , 
            GrandRecordId  =  ids.InsertedId,   -- Id translation target
            Name    
        from
            @Records r
            inner join @GrandRecordIds ids 
                on ids.ParamId = r.GrandRecordId -- Id translation source
    ) 
    as source on source.Id = target.Id

    when matched then
        update set
            GrandRecordId  =  source.GrandRecordId, 
            Name           =  source.Name    

    when not matched by target then                                                         
        insert (    
            GrandRecordId , 
            Name          )
        values (
            source.GrandRecordId , 
            source.Name          )

    when not matched by source 
        and target.GrandRecordId in (select InsertedId from @GrandRecordIds) then
           delete

    output                 -- collecting translation Ids
        isnull(inserted.Id, deleted.Id),
        isnull(source.Id, deleted.Id), 
        $action
    into @RecordIds (
        InsertedId  , 
        ParamId     , 
        [Action]    );


    delete from @RecordIds where [Action] = 'DELETE';


    -- save ChildRecords

    merge into dbo.ChildRecords as target
        using 
        (
            select
                Id        ,
                RecordId  =  ids.InsertedId,    -- Id translation target
                Name        
            from
                @ChildRecords cr
                inner join @RecordIds ids 
                    on ids.ParamId = cr.RecordId -- Id translation source
        ) 
        as source on source.Id = target.Id

    when matched then
        update set
            RecordId = source.RecordId , 
            Name     = source.Name

    when not matched by target then
        insert (    
            RecordId , 
            Name     )
        values (
            source.RecordId , 
            source.Name     )

    when not matched by source and target.RecordId in (select InsertedId from @RecordIds) then
        delete;
end;
```

### Important notice

> In the MERGE statement the source and the target tables
>   MUST have clustered indexes on their join columns!
>   This prevents deadlocks and guarantees insertion order.

The *join columns* are in `as source on source.Id = target.Id` line of MERGE statement.

That is why the User Defined Table Types above have `primary key clustered` in their definitions.

That is why the Negative Identities are ever increasing and start with MinValue.

---

See my article about the technique on [www.codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1153556/How-to-Save-Object-Graph-in-Master-detail-Relation) and download the source code from there to see how it works.